# In Djano checkbox i am getting False value though POST data shows checbox has been checked?

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

I am having a boolean field in my model which disaply as checkbox in view and I am running custom validations upon it.
However i am always getting its value as "False" in my model form's clean method even user checks that check box, i read somewher that django automatically converts value as False.

Can someone guide me in my clean method how should i check whether checkbox is checked or not? Any help on this issue will be appreciated

My model is as follows:-

```
discard_word =  models.BooleanField(max_length=30)
```

My modelform view as follows:-

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_with_post = FormSet(request.POST,queryset=page_query)
    if form_with_post.is_valid():
```

My form as follows:-

```
class Un_Verified_bn_in_form(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Un_Verified_bn_in_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
        self.fields['phrase'].required = False
        self.fields['phrase'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['id'].required = False
        self.fields['alternate_phrase'].required = False
        #self.fields['discard_word'].required = False                                                                     
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    replace_phrase = cleaned_data.get("alternate_phrase")
    discard_word_val = cleaned_data.get("discard_word")           
    if (replace_phrase == u'' or replace_phrase == None) and (discard_word_val == False ):
        raise ValidationError('You need to select atleast one field')
    return cleaned_data 

class Meta:
    model = Un_Verified_bn_in
    fields = ('id','phrase','alternate_phrase','discard_word')
    exclude = ('time','verified_by_usr','verified_by_admin','author')
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? `cleaned_data['discard_word']` is a boolean value indicating the status of the field. Although note you should compare to `None` and `False` with `==`, but `if foo is None` and `if not bool_value`.

Comment: Daniel problem is cleaned_data['discard_word'] always returns False though checkbox has been checked

Comment: Maybe you should show the rest of the view. What is FormSet, for example? And what is in the template?

Comment: i did not post formset because i thought it would not help that much as in request.POST i am getting value as u'discard_word': [u'on'] but in cleaned_data['discard_word'] it becomes false. Somewhether I read that Django automatically converts all boolean values to False

Comment: if i print self in my clean method i get following  <tr><th><label for="id_form-0-discard_word">Discard word:</label></th><td><input checked="checked" id="id_form-0-discard_word" name="form-0-discard_word" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is correct way to solve the problem as Browser puts "on" value when checkbox has signed.
So i am using that in my clean function i am using self.data instead of cleaned_data

```
    try:
        discard_word_val= self.data[self.prefix+'-discard_word']
    except:
        discard_word_val = False
    if discard_word_val == u'on':
        discard_word_val = True
```